# Google login error with the google_sign_in package in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, google-signin

I'm trying to make a Google login with my app, but I the login constantly fails with this error:

```
I/flutter (16839): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: , null)
```

The Android logcat spits out this error:

```
2018-11-22 22:47:25.329 2505-17072/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
2018-11-22 22:47:25.433 2505-16856/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
2018-11-22 22:47:25.702 14421-16174/com.google.android.gms.ui E/bqye: *~*~*~ Channel {0} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
        Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
        at bqyf.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):1)
        at bqye.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):2)
        at bqye.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):1)
        at bqrh.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):20)
        at pwb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):47)
        at pwb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):65)
        at com.google.android.gms.signin.activity.SignInChimeraActivity.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):28)
        at amho.call(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at qcr.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at qiv.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2018-11-22 22:47:29.146 1731-1731/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2018-11-22 22:47:29.172 2505-16856/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
2018-11-22 22:47:29.727 1678-1711/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
```

The login function looks like this:

```
Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await googleSignIn.signIn();
      print(_currentUser.email);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Don't mark this as a duplicate right away, I've read the other posts and yes, my package name is correct and yes, I added an SHA-1 and SHA-256 key to my Firebase project. They're also correct(I assume, since they're freshly generated with keytool). My google_services.json is also freshly downloaded.

Comment: are you using an emulator?

Comment: @AmEénÁhsAn Yes, i am, but it supports Google Play Services and the Google login.

Comment: try rebuilding the app after deleting the build directory

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried every solution mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google), then try to follow the suggested solution mentioned in the comment:

> try rebuilding the app after deleting the build directory

But before rebuilding the app, you can also run `flutter clean` from your terminal. It deletes build-cache which is in the `/build` folder