# Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

The dialog (Google form) for the credentials is opened successfully, but after I fill my credentials I'm getting this error. I followed the instructions from [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in). Created a Firebase project, enabled the Google Drive API (that's what I need for now) from the Google APIs Console.

The code throwing the exception:

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  ],
);

await _googleSignIn.signIn();
```

That's the stack trace:

```
E/flutter ( 5068): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 5068): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
E/flutter ( 5068): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:551:7)
E/flutter ( 5068): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:292:18)
E/flutter ( 5068): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5068): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:226:58)
E/flutter ( 5068): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5068): #3      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:268:20)
E/flutter ( 5068): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:339:48)
E/flutter ( 5068): #5      ThatsMyComponentState.theSignInFuction.<anonymous closure> (package:my_app/widgets/my_file.dart:666:45)
E/flutter ( 5068): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5068): #6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
E/flutter ( 5068): #7      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
E/flutter ( 5068): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter ( 5068): #9      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter ( 5068): #10     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
E/flutter ( 5068): #11     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 5068): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:184:20)
E/flutter ( 5068): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
E/flutter ( 5068): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
E/flutter ( 5068): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 5068): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
E/flutter ( 5068): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
E/flutter ( 5068): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)
```

The version of the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in) plugin is 4.0.0.

That's the output of **flutter doctot -v**:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.253], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\src\flutter-0.7.3\flutter
• Framework revision 5391447fae (10 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
• Engine revision 7375a0f414
• Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 32.0.1
• Dart plugin version 182.5124
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
• IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.6
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
• For information about installing plugins, see
  https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.30.2)
• VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension not installed; install from
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To all: pay attention to the exception code `ApiException: 10` and refer to the docs first - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes Make sure you're fixing the right issue. For example code 7 would just mean 'no internet connection'.

Comment: Run ./gradlew signingReport, it's under the app Android folder. Add SHA1 in google Firebase Google Sign in configuration. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth . You will need an SHA1 for each computer you work on.

Comment: @KirillKarmazin any idea what 12500 is?
E/flutter (23795): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)

Comment: My issue was running the app in the debug mode yet the keys in the console had the SHA for release key. Watch out on this use flutter run --release

Answer (score 414):

I run into the same issue just now. This might happens if you are running on debug and you did **not** register a `SHA` fingerprint in firebase.
I solved it by generating a `debug.keystore` by running:
`keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`

and registering it inside the app on Firebase. Don't forget to download the new `google-services.json` after that.

See also [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth).

[image]

**Edit**
If you are not able to use authenticate **in release mode** try the following:

-Add the SHA certificate fingerprints of the release key.

`keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>`

For more details on that see here on the section `"get release certificate"` https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

If your authentication is still not working, probably it is because you downloaded the app from Playstore and you enabled the  **"App Signing by Google Play Feature"**
Then for this case, go to play store publish console and go to app signing under release management. There you will find the SHA certificate fingerprint to register in Firebase console.

[image]

Final step: If it still not working, double check that you have put the right fingerprints with `cd android` then `./gradlew signingReport` (check `Variant: debug, release` ). It should work now. But if not, try to run terminal run the command `flutter clean`.

Comment: Thanks for this. This helped. Worthwhile noting that both the SHA1 and SHA256 keys had to be added for the auth to work

Comment: @TSR this worked but I didn't have to download a new google-services.json.

Comment: FYI, I had the same error even after configuring my sha fingerprints. Turns out i also had to add a support email address per https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25909#issuecomment-497378619 .

Comment: @MichaelNelson this was my problem, too

Comment: Where do you find <path-to-production-keystore>? How do you create this file?

Comment: Only SHA1 is needed.

Comment: your edit linking to "If you've published your app using Play App Signing, a requirement when using Android App Bundle, you can get your SHA-1 from the Google Play Console on the Release > Setup > App Integrity page" saved me! thank you!

Comment: for additional support, refer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091158/10505343](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091158/10505343)

Comment: awesome. this was exactly the problem i was going through. Thank you.

Comment: I ran into this just now and want to EMPHASIS that having *just* SHA-256 in your Firebase project config will get you this error, you MUST also have the SHA-1 fingerprint despite the android cli tool `keytool` warning that SHA-1 is a security risk & will be disabled in the future.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me, I forgot to put SHA1 & SHA256 for Google Play Console in Firebase Keys.

Comment: When I hit this error it was caused by not having google play installed on the phone emulator.

Comment: In my case, I was using Firebase so it was required to enable google provider in Firebase Authentication

Comment: No need to download google-services.json again, just add SHA-1 from playstore

Comment: default password is "android"

Answer (score 164):

I spent ages trying to fix this.

**1. Open grade.properties** This file is found under: {{YOUR PROJECT}}/android/gradle.properties

[image]

**2. Add the following argument to 'org.gradle.jvmargs' as shown in the screenshot.**

-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m

[image]

**3. Right click on 'gradlew' and go to 'Open in Terminal'**
This file is found under {{YOUR PROJECT}}/android/gradlew

[image]

**4. Type in the following command.**

```
gradlew signingReport
```

If did not work first try second command:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

**5. Wait for the compilation to finish and your SHA keys should be printed out for you.**

[image]

Use these keys to authenticate your app in https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: For me that is the only thing that worked, my keytool generated not working SHA-1 / SHA-256

Comment: If step 4 didn't work, call gradlew like this instead: ./gradlew signingReport

Comment: Chiming in to say this is also the only thing that worked for me. Tried everything else and spent days trying to solve the issue before finding this.

Comment: Getting this error: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Comment: this is the easiest method! this should be accepted.

Comment: The best answer. Perfect.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. After spending hours on this issue, finally, this worked for me.

Comment: The best answer. Thannks!.

Comment: Best answer, easy to follow and simply works

Comment: Yes worked, thaks. BTW if you get heap memory error, then try: `-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx1536M`

Comment: And what if you don't use firebase?

Comment: At first, this works for me. But after a minute it won't work again.

Comment: Sometimes it works, then after restarting the app it won't work again.

Comment: it works finally!!! I don't understand why Google makes this so clumsy on their own platform. I had no problems with google_sign_in on iOS.

Comment: If it didn't work and you are in a new project, try to build the project first, then run the ./gradlew signingReport command.

Comment: Thanks so much! Only method that worked for me as well.

Comment: by using step 2 it is creating an issue while running "flutter build apk --release" command.
Issue is I changed SHA-1 in Google Developers console

Answer (score 112):

Open the Firebase console and click on the settings icon.

You will see the list of the apps connected to your Firebase project

For Android

1. Open terminal inside your flutter project
2. `cd android`
3. `./gradlew signingReport` or `gradlew signingReport`
4. Paste your SHA1 key
5. Download and replace the `google-services.json`
6. `flutter clean`

IOS:

1. Configure your Firebase project
2. Select IOS
3. Enter your Bundle ID
4. Download credetials
5. Download and replace `GoogleService-info.plist`

Add this to your info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>**INSERT HERE YOUR RESERVED_CLIENT_ID FROM GoogleService-Info.plist**</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: gradlew signingReport helps me a lot, because I first I just use the wrong keystore. And with that command, you get definitely the right one.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling all the day to find a solution , I gave you up-vote :)

Answer (score 106):

The following solution works in flutter project:

Step 1: Generate **SHA1** and **SHA256** keys.
Step 2: Add both the SHA1 and SHA256 to firebase. *(in you app settings)*
Step 3: Download **google-services.json** to **android/app** in your project folder.
Step 4: In your terminal run the command `flutter clean` .
Step 5: Run your flutter app.

For more information visit:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: clean is very important

Comment: This is the right solution.

Additionally, if Firebase package-name and project package-name (path) do not match, you still get this error code:10.

Answer (score 42):

When I came across this problem, I tried all other solutions described in this post. None of these worked. Eventually I figured it out: In my situation I had to make sure to have my "support email" set.

[image: Public Setting Support Email]

Comment: This was helpful man thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 39):

For me I didn't need to add extra SHAs, I realized I didn't enable the **Google Sign-in method** in the **Authentication** tab in **Firebase console**

[image: Enabling google sign-in method in Firebase console]

Comment: Tried all the rest - only to realize that your simple solution was the one I needed!

Answer (score 23):

Additional steps you might have to take in order for google_sign_in to work:

- Link GooglePlay with Firebase [(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27599)

[image: ][2]]

- If you could run Google Sign In during debug but NOT in release, there is a high chance that you did not add your release key's SHA1 and SHA256 to firebase.
  To get the release key's SHAs, use `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/key.jks -alias key`

[image: console]
You should end up with total of **at least 6 SHA credentials**: 2 from the debug key, 2 from Google Play linking, and 2 from the release key. Note that you do not need to redownload the google-services.json file after adding the release SHA credentials to firebase.

[image: Firebase]

- Add GooglePlay Proguard rules [(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19102)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19102)

```
# Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }

# GooglePlay Services
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.common.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
```

Answer (score 21):

If your released app is not working properly, and you are using Google Play Signing, **Copy the SHA from your play store account**, the one from your local key will not work
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is the missing essential step to putting my app in production that had me trial-and-erroring for hours. Other solutions here were only good for building debug versions.

Comment: I have this issue, my app that has been on the Google Play App Store suddenly not working, but unfortunately the 'App Signing' section is no longer available.

Comment: ahhh I got it, it is now in the 'App Integrity' section. and then copy that SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to Firebase Console (project settings -> general ->  scroll down until you see your Android app)

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution for the error `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10`: I solved it by adding more keys to the firebase. initially I thought it was stupid and useless, then in the end it turned out to be the solution (I added up to 10 SHA, don't worry if that's a lot).

1. ***Where did I find all these keys?***

I found all these keys by entering the android folder and typing the command `./gradlew signingReport` (I use linux, it also works on mac. For windows the command is `gradlew signingReport`)

2. ***After that?***

After that, he printed out a very long list of keys in my terminal, and I took all the ones that were different, that were at the top of the list.

Note: you will get all the keys (both debug and release) of each package of the app, but rest assured that all those of the packages are the same and only for debugging (so you will have to take these same keys only once)

3. ***Finally***

Once you have all the app keys, go to your project's Firebase settings, scroll down and add any keys you found.
After that, you will need to download the `google-services.json` file again and run a `flutter clean` in your project's local folder on your computer.

Now you can build your app and see if it works!

I hope this could help someone.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was finally able to resolve it. :)

Answer (score 11):

The answer that given early are right. None of them are false. But if you still face the error `PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)`. One thing that your should check is your `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs`

[image]

1. Go to : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Select your project on the top left screen
3. Create Client ID base on your platform (iOS or Android)
4. Just follow the next steps

Once you successfully generate the client ID, then your application will works as expected.

--- Note ---

But first, make sure you have regitered your `SHA-1`, `package id` `email support` and has been download the `google service json` from your firebase console project.

Answer (score 9):

"Flutter clean" its the piece that everybody is missing after register the SHA1 in Firebase Console!

Answer (score 8):

You have missed configuration step enable google login on firebase.

> Google sign-in is automatically configured on your connected iOS and web apps. To set up Google sign-in for your Android apps, you need to add the SHA1 fingerprint for each app on your Project Settings.

✅ **Just complete these enough steps below**

1. Enable **Google** Auth Method
2. Configure **certificate fingerprints** in your current project at `project-level setting`. [How to Generate certificate](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth).
3. Select email for **Project support email**
4. Download `google-service.json` into your project.
5. Run `flutter clean`
6. start `flutter run`

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One reason that you might be experiencing this error is if you did not fill out google's OAuth consent form. This is a new change to Firebase.

Here are the steps you need to follow to fill out the consent form for your app:

1. Navigate to the google api console (currently at https://console.developers.google.com), make sure you are logged into your account which your firebase project is created under.
2. Select your project from the "select a project" dropdown in top left of the developer console.
3. In the left hand pane travel to "credentials" and then switch to the "OAuth consent screen".
4. Under "Application name" enter your application's public name
5. Under "Application logo" upload a local image file of your application
6. Under "Support email" enter the same support email listed in your firebase application.

[image: Your screen should now look like this example by step 6]

7. Scroll down and fill out the "Application Homepage Link", "Application Privacy Policy Link", and "Application Terms of Service Link" by adding **http://** before the authorized domain which your firebase app lives at.

[image: Here is a highlighted example of how these regions should be filled out in step 7]

8. Click Save

These steps worked for me! While the link may not still exist, I'd like to reference the source of this solution [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed)

Comment: Is it actually an answer to the question?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried to update my answer to be more specific--please let me know if it is now appropriate--and if not, how I can improve it.

Comment: Do you need to "Submit for Verification", or just "Save"?

Comment: If you arrived here, for your mental sanity, do no add a logo to the oauth screen consent. It's not needed and it triggers a verification.

Answer (score 5):

make sure you have added

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

in android/build.gradle and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in **android/app/build.gradle**. Also, make sure applicationId in **android/app/build.gradle** is the same as your package name in **AndroidManifest.xml**(You may forget to change applicationId after changing package name sometimes). This applicatioonId or package  name in manifest file should be the
name of your android package name in firebase app.

Answer (score 5):

For platform exception 10, try this:

1. Generate a new SHA1 fingerprint on your machine,
2. Go to your firebase android app setting in Firebase Console
3. Click on add new fingerprint in your android app settings
4. Paste the new SHA1 fingerprint into the field
5. Generate a new json config file
6. Replace the config file in android directory
7. Run flutter clean
8. Run your project

Answer (score 4):

In my case, none of the answers solved the problem. After some thinking, I realized that sometime ago I have **changed the package name of my application**. If it is your case, you should simply create another application inside your Firebase project with your new package name and download google-services.json file again.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me also when I have reinstalled my OS.
Just run `./gradlew signingReport`and copy the SHA-1 and SHA-256 into Firebase config "add fingerprint"

Comment: solved my problem also

Answer (score 4):

If your implementation works everywhere but not on Android, make sure that you use the correct **WEB** `clientId` supplied to `GoogleProvider(clientId: clientId)` when using `firebase_ui_auth` package.

I repeat: Use **WEB** `clientId` to make Google SignIn work on **Android**.

This is completely counterintuitive and not documented anywhere. It took me three days of trial and error until I finally found [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33393#issuecomment-964728679).

Comment: For me it was to opposite. I used clientId to make it work on web, and it didn't work on Android until I removed it. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107532

Comment: This one worked after I tried everything else.

Comment: This perfectly work for me when i use it on my android

Answer (score 3):

This might seem silly, but that just happened to me now (after having some experience working with firebase in the past). **I noticed that I did not enable Google authentication.** Make sure you do that, as you might still see the login prompt (showing you your phone's google users, without it being enabled).

Comment: where do I enable thant?

Comment: @AhmedAlbarody In your firebase console - choose authentication and then you need to enable the services you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all of the above answers and none worked. I'm putting my solution here in case someone runs into an edge case like mine:

1. Mine didn't work with the above answers because I'm installing the app via **Firebase App Tester (Firebase Distribution)** and it resigned the app with entirely **new test certificates**, not the usual debug or release certificates you can get from Android Studio
2. To solve it, go to Firebase App Distribution from Firebase Console and copy the test certificates SHA-1 and SHA-256
   [image: firebase app distribution certificates]
3. Enter these new certificates in Firebase Project Settings

Answer (score 3):

This answer has already more 30 answer but this is more COMPLETE STEP BY STEP APPROACH to solve this bug.

1. Most likely you do not have debug.keystore in your C/User/.android directory. To generate one, do the following

> $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android
> -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

use organization name Android
country code US
and name Android Debug

2. when you have done so, navigate to your android flutter directory where gradlew is located and do the following

> ./gradlew signingReport

3. You will have list of SHA1 SHA256 keys. copy both keys that is named debug.keystore to your flutter project firebase project settings (where you download google-services.json)

Flutter clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks. use `./gradlew signingReport` to get SHA1 when test with emulator is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should generate SHA-1 and SHA-256 for each pc that you used. And add them all to firebase project settings.

And you should fill the form in [OAuth Consent](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) tab.

Answer (score 2):

If it previously worked but now are using a different PC, you'll need to add new SHA-1/SHA-256 fingerprints generated by that PC to your project in [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/). A good step-by-step example on doing that:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091158/5365164

Comment: By explaining the rootcause, it's much easier to find the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue. I checked the signingReport and found that the release SHA1 and SHA256 were different from others. I added these values in firebase and re-downloaded the google-services.json. This solved the issue.

Also, run `flutter clean` before building apk.

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue has many replies already but I haven't seen this one yet. I solved ApiException: 10 by cleaning up!

1. Removed unused OAuth 2.0 Client IDs from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Removed unused fingerprints from the Firebase console.
3. Download google-services.json again

Comment: Removed unused fingerprints and update google-services.json solved for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure SHA-1 must be a debug key which is generated in your system only, and then download google-services.json file append that to your project

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue and took 5 hours to get it solved. I remember I read somewhere that API Exception 10 means that there is an issue with the fingerprints. So, it had to be the keystore or a misconfiguration in firebase. Eventually, it was the keystore. I'm still not sure of why this worked but this is what I did. I'm using Windows 10:

1.) Make sure that on the file **android/build.gradle** I had the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

2.) I added these two lines to the file **android/gradle.properties**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

3.) Navigated to **C:\Users\YOURUSER\.android** and deleted the following:

```
debug.keystore
debug.keystore.lock
```

4.) Open the terminal as admin, and generated the debug keystore in this directory.

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Obtained the fingerprints:

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

5.) Added the SHA1 fingerprints to the configuration in firebase

Comment: all the above didnt work but this did... thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you do this:

- Enable google sign in from your firebase console
- Put your SHA-1 when setup your android firebase app
- After signed in with the same account with which you have created the Firebase project.You have fill in this consenst
  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Answer (score 1):

However, the answers given above are correct, but still, if you are having issue then don't forget to verify the signingConfig {} section of the app/build.gradle. It should not have any unwanted keystore file reference, which may be causing a mismatch with google-services.json and the keystore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a silly mistake,make sure that your applicationId in firebase like : 'com.example.appname' matches exactly with the applicationId in your app/src/build.gradle file,under the defaultConfig{}.No spelling errors,no upper case,lower case letter conflicts.In my case one letter was upper case which caused all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the steps suggested by others
running
`./gradlew clean`
worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the date on your phone manually also results in a Platform Exception when trying to sign in with google. At least with the flutter google-sign-in library.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was at the point that when I added flavors to my project, I set a different application-id for each flavor. But at the Firebase console, I had only one. Double-check the application ID, please.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your SHA-1 and SHA-256 to your Firebase project. If you've published your app using Play App Signing, a requirement when using Android App Bundle, you can get your SHA-1 from the Google Play Console on the Release > Setup > App Integrity page.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you have already enabled OAuth in the Google Cloud Console for your Firebase Project.

1. go into the the android folder i.e. `myProjectName/android`
2. run `./gradlew signingReport` (Mac/Linux) or `gradlew.bat signingReport` (Windows), to get the hashes of the debug and release key
3. now go into the project settings of your firebase project and add the hashes under the fingerprint section of your apps
4. run `flutter clean` to make sure not to use old data
5. run `flutterfire configure` (this will add the necessary `oauth_client` entries in the `google-services.json` under `android/app`)
6. run your app, now it should be working

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was I didn't add signinConfigs for debug in the `android/app/build.gradle`. I only added for release so the app wasn't working as I tested it.

```
android {
    ...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
        # It started working when I added the following debug section.
        debug {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

I got this style of "referencing the keystore from the app" from https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reference-the-keystore-from-the-app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on android tried all above but not fixed. In my case issue was very simple. In my project i had **already add google-service.json** file and in my code pass **clientId** too

[image: codeScreenshot]

**clientId is optional param and its least to error.**

check this too

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In **android/app/build.gradle** I changed the dependencies from **com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3**/**com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1** to **com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1**/**com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0**. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

While registering the app in Firebase I changed my applicationId to something that suits my app. However, this resulted in a second Flutter app being installed on my phone when I ran the debugger (Of course, due to the change in applicationId). So the thing that worked for my situation, was to `remove` both the installations and `re-install` the app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above and nothing worked.
My mistake was I had multiple android studio version folders in my drive and  I was feeding wrong SHA1 key in firebase settings.

Answer (score 0):

Building an appbundle (which is recommended by Google Play and Flutter) will cause this error.  Building an apk will resolve this.

See issue [58194425](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194425/platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the signing certs you are using on the firebase console is same as what is used in signingConfigs >> debug configuration in app/build.gradle file while still in development. Missmatch causes error.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me. I did a small refactor in a new project. I thought I was using my old `google-services.json` file but I had been using the wrong file. I tried everything else for two days before realizing this simple error.

Answer (score 0):

This was helped to me (was a problem importing the SHA1)

cd .android
i used and copied the SHA1 key and pasted in firebase, project configuration, android application, SHA certificate

keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

and i created also one more key with:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkeytwo -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

and used this to take one more SHA key:

keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkeytwo -storepass android -keypass android

i copied and pasted adding one more key in my firebase project.

also downloaded the google-services.json and pasted in Android/app inside the flutter project.

This worked properly, my pubspec.yml depencies:

```
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.1
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6
  firebase_core: ^0.4.2+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.14
```

my code:

```
    Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed: () async {
        await signInWithGoogle()
            .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user.displayName))
            .catchError((e) => print(e));

      },

    );
  }

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
  print(user.displayName.toString());
  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return user;
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();

  print("User Sign Out");
}
```

I hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error:
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: **7**: ,null) Maybe solution is good for you.

And I realise my debug device (android debug mode) not connected to internet.
I think authentication is failed so method return null or user equal to null.

Returned variable must check before using.

Comment: I find it difficult to follow your answer: can you get help using English (not *my* 1st language)?

Answer (score 0):

i too had same issue.

> 1. i had set Consent Screen.
> 2. Added google_play_services.json
> 3. had enabled Google SignIn
> 4. added required plugin in flutter
>
> but it was not working, i was getting same API Exception-10, gsm error
>
> after adding SHA1 it started working

Answer (score 0):

Works great for me:

Change the `minSdkVersion` to **`21`** in **all of your files** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

You can use real device, as this issue persists on the emmulator or simmulator sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your java bin folder:

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin**

Now type in the below command in your cmd replacing **your_user_name** with your owns:

`keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, turns out that, after setting the SHA-1 and SHA256 keys in Google Firebase, the json files got changed. Also changing the project name in settings in firebase also changed the json files. I re-downloaded the new json files and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything but still you can not log in use google then I think you use an emulator. Switch to real device and hope it will be work

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. but I solved it by taking a simple step.

First, let me tell you how the problem happened with my project:

I have linked my Flutter app to the Google Cloud Console to use Google Sign-In without Firebase. And it was working. Later, I linked the app (the Flutter app) to Firebase to use phone authentication. After this, when I tried to log in with Google Sign In, this error was thrown: "PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:, null, null)".

The reason was, When I call this method:

final response = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

The request was sent to Firebase, not Google Cloud Console.
So, I tried this solution, and the error was solved:

1. The solution is to just open your "google_services.json" file and delete the "client_id" from the this code in google_services.json file.

"oauth_client": [
        {
         "client_id": "872887541893-6rib4t0mk07gu1l80emetda6o65e2m76.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
2. Run this command on your app's VSC terminal.
   2.1.flutter clean
2.2. flutter pub get
then run your app.
it worked for me. Let me know if you have an issue with the above explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set my android application id.  for some reason flutter set my application id to com.example.dev.  Changing the application Id fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting `google-services.json` from my project and deleting `SHA-1` from firebase ,and also deleting `keystore.jsk` then creating new `keystore.jsk` and getting the new `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` and adding theme to firebase and getting new `google-services.json`  from firebase and add it to my project .
after all this delete your app from the emulator and then `flutter clean` then `flutter run` .

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the app’s cache and data in device settings. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried everything and nothing fixed it.

What fixed this for me was that for some reason I was supplying a `clientId` parameter to my `GoogleSignIn()` call. Removing this fixed it for me.

I went from:

```dart
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(clientId: clientId).signIn();
```

to

```dart
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

All keys were already added. But then for me deleting all the keys and adding them again worked like charm!