# Manifest versionCode not found

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, flutter

I'm running my flutter project in android emulator. I was facing the following error. Screenshot attached.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Error running com.******.swivy. Manifest versionCode not found
Unable to read manifest info from /Users/muruganandham.kuppan/swivy/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

[image]

But, I can see the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in respective file path.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project ?

Comment: This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54696963/2515572

Comment: deleting the build folder in the project directory helped me solve the issue. #flutter #versioncodenotfound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54696963/2515572) helped me.

solved it by generating a `debug.keystore` and registering it inside the app on Firebase. Don't forget to download the new google-services.json after that.

See also https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Answer (score 4):

This may happen if you had deleted `versionCode` and `versionName` in your `build.gradle(app)`.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.package"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29

    // make sure you have these two variables
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is what I think is a bug in the flutter create templates. In the build.gradle files they create, they have these stanzas:

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
   throw new GradleException("versionCode not found. Define flutter.versionCode in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
```

The workaround for this is to change the lines in your build.gradle from something like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
}
```

to something like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
}
```

and remove the flutterVersionCode and flutterVersionName stanzas.

The fix to the bug will probably be something like defaulting to a value if the version information isn't in the local.properties.

got it from this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18983