# How to catch errors in GoogleSignIn signInSilently?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code that I am using to log a user in silently

```
try {
    result = await GoogleSignIn().signInSilently().catchError((x) {
      print(x);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

If the user cannot sign in silently, it results in an error.

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_required, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4: , null))
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to catch the exception.  catchError nor the catch block are being hit.  How do I catch this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `print(e);` line in the catch statement.  'e' is not a string so an error occurs.  I don't know why but no breakpoints are hit in the catch statement for this error and no error is output to the console.  If I put a catch statement around a function that calls the login code ie.

```
void tryLogin(){
  try{
    myLoginLogic();
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Then I do get an error message

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

So to be clear the correct code would be

```
try {
  result = await GoogleSignIn().signInSilently().catchError((e) {
    print(e.toString());
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```

*Why code doesn't break on error and no message is written to the console for the original function I don't know.  Also what I don't understand is why, even when the catch statement is written without errors, in debug mode the code breaks on the `signInSilently()` line.*

Answer (score 2):

Do the following in your method

```
try {
    result = await GoogleSignIn().signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).catchError((x) {
      print(x);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

By default `suppressErrors = true` suppressing the error messages you want to catch.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_sign_in)

The SignInSilently method is used to suppress error messages thus not throwing the exception you want to catch.

From the docs of this method:

```
  /// When [suppressErrors] is set to `false` and an error occurred during sign in
  /// returned Future completes with [PlatformException] whose `code` can be
  /// either [kSignInRequiredError] (when there is no authenticated user) or
  /// [kSignInFailedError] (when an unknown error occurred).
```

Full Method

```
 /// Attempts to sign in a previously authenticated user without interaction.
  ///
  /// Returned Future resolves to an instance of [GoogleSignInAccount] for a
  /// successful sign in or `null` if there is no previously authenticated user.
  /// Use [signIn] method to trigger interactive sign in process.
  ///
  /// Authentication process is triggered only if there is no currently signed in
  /// user (that is when `currentUser == null`), otherwise this method returns
  /// a Future which resolves to the same user instance.
  ///
  /// Re-authentication can be triggered only after [signOut] or [disconnect].
  ///
  /// When [suppressErrors] is set to `false` and an error occurred during sign in
  /// returned Future completes with [PlatformException] whose `code` can be
  /// either [kSignInRequiredError] (when there is no authenticated user) or
  /// [kSignInFailedError] (when an unknown error occurred).
  Future<GoogleSignInAccount> signInSilently({bool suppressErrors = true}) {
    final Future<GoogleSignInAccount> result = _addMethodCall('signInSilently');
    if (suppressErrors) {
      return result.catchError((dynamic _) => null);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Reference

- [Google Sign In Plugin Repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_sign_in)
- [Method Source Code Starting Line 283](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/9dfc97027db9803714c69f63136c1ce2e7e8ad80/packages/google_sign_in/lib/google_sign_in.dart)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.  The problem is that the error is being thrown and it just doesn't get caught then my function that wraps the signInSilently code returns a _TypeError type and doesn't run the code in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google) might help.

Checklists :

1. Did not register a sha fingerprint.
2. Make sure to have my "support email" set.
3. Enable the Google Sign-in method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.  The problem is that the catch code is not hit ever.

Answer (score 0):

The `catchError` block is actually getting hit if you use `suppressErrors = false`
Try the following code and see what it prints on your console.

```
result = await GoogleSignIn().signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).
  catchError((x) {
    print("inside catchError");
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me on my way as I deleted the print(e) line!