# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Please read the question before sitting it to duplicate

I'm trying to make google sign in feature in my app but this error keeps showing up

I've done the following:

- added support email
- activated google signin in flutter console
- generated the sha1 and signed it to firebase
- added the following dependencies:

  - firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
  - firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+8
  - google_sign_in: ^4.0.4
  - rxdart: ^0.22.0
  - cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7
- updated gradle to version 5.1.1 (latest for the time being posted)

what I already tried:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25640 this didn't help me
- [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google) this is not quite related also didn't help me

here is the brains of the app

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AuthService {

  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  Observable<FirebaseUser> user;
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile;
  PublishSubject loading = PublishSubject();

  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);

    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async {
    loading.add(true);

    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("signed in " + user.displayName);

    updateUserData(user);

    loading.add(false);
    print("signed in " + user.displayName);
    return user;
  }

  void updateUserData(FirebaseUser user) async {
    DocumentReference ref = _db.collection('users').document(user.uid);

    return ref.setData({
      'uid': user.uid,
      'email': user.email,
      'photoURL': user.photoUrl,
      'displayName': user.displayName,
      'lastSeen': DateTime.now()
    }, merge: true);
  }

  void signOut() {
    _auth.signOut();
  }
}

final AuthService authService = AuthService();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33393#issuecomment-510395178
you don't have to add the links listed in the comment, just update the picture with anything and it will work

the docs needs to be updated

Answer (score 1):

For me adding scopes and hostedDomain in GoogleSignIn method works.

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(
        scopes: ['email', 'profile'],
        hostedDomain: '',
      ).signIn();
```