# Flutter: google_sign_in - com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, oauth

After reading through countless similar issues
e.g.:

- [Flutter : PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null) when using google_sign_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541415/flutter-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-ap)
- [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)

and other documentation, changing my Firebase configuration, google-services.json, creating and recreating countless Gogle Cloud credentials, I have finally decided to post my issue here in hopes of help from others.

My Flutter app is supposed to connect with the Google Calendar of the user logging in, to synchronize their events in their calendar across their devices.

This requires the sensitive scopes:

```dart
static const List<String> scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'];
```

Secondly, to sign in with google, I tried using https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth, but after that failed due to Googles migration away from loopback URLs, I found https://pub.dev/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth, which uses https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in to let the user sign in, and then provide me with an AuthClient.

Trying this out successfully opens a dialog to the user, asking them, which Google Account they would like to sign in with, but upon selecting any, I get the (now dreaded) `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10`

Through reading issues others had with Google oAuth, I found the following, leading me to my current configuration:

### Getting the certificates

- I got the playstore signing and playstore upload certificate hashes from the Play Console
- The debug certificate hashes were found using `gradlew signingReport`

### Firebase:

- Both the SHA1 and SHA256 hashes have to be uploaded for each certificate
- I added that for the playstore signing, playstore upload, and my apps debug certificate
- I re-downloaded the google-services.json and added it to my app
- The support email was set
- Flutter clean was run before cold starting the app

### Google Cloud:

- All 3 of these certificates SHA1 hashes have a separate Android oAuth credential
- I decided to test it by using my debug certificate, so I downloaded the debug clientId and implemented it in my code:

```dart
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  clientId: debugClientId, // Technically unused
  serverClientId: debugClientId,
  forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
  scopes: scopes,
);
```

- The consent dialog had to be setup properly, which I did by filling out all fields whilst keeping the dialog in testing mode, to prevent it from requiring verification
- The consent dialog, since it is in testing mode, required me to add all emails which it would be enabled for, which I did for the emails that I would be clicking in the sign in with Google dialog

### Actually signing in:

- The app was built
- I wait until the appropriate time to ask the user for permission
- The sign in with Google dialog was called using the below dart code:

```dart
GoogleSignInAccount currentUser? = await _googleSignIn.signIn()
```

However, this just yields the issue as described above, here with its complete StackTrace:

```
I/flutter ( 6057): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
I/flutter ( 6057): #0      GoogleSignInApi.signIn (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:221:7)
I/flutter ( 6057): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6057): #1      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:278:30)
I/flutter ( 6057): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6057): #2      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:431:5)
I/flutter ( 6057): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6057): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
I/flutter ( 6057): #0      GoogleSignInApi.signIn (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:221:7)
I/flutter ( 6057): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6057): #1      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:278:30)
I/flutter ( 6057): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6057): #2      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:431:5)
I/flutter ( 6057): <asynchronous suspension>
```

At this point, I am considering canceling the feature entirely and staying with local calendars, as it is not a core feature, but this has to work somehow, right?