# Flutter google_sign_in get weird issue PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in for google sign-in in one other my running project. It was working well but I changed my google Firestore account so I have to do setup on my new account and replace **"google-services.json"** file new one in the project.

When I tried to login by google after all setup regraded to new Firestore account, Always get below issue.

> `PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)`

I have done all the setup, added *support email* to project settings and added *SHA-1* like below Q/A

[Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)

Don't know what's is going wrong?? If I created a new project and add the same **"google-services.json"** and do the setup for google login then it's working.

Anything I missing or any conflict.

~PS: I have done https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent and google login working well will fresh project.