# OAuth consent screen blank in android app with Google Fit

Tags: android, oauth, google-fit

I'm trying to use the Google Fit API in my application, after the user is prompted to choose a Google account the OAuth consent screen should be displayed, however I only get a blank popup with a indefinite loading indicator, this popup will stay like that unless I cancel it.

[Image of the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epsks.png)

No error messages are displayed, only if I cancel the sign-in flow I would get an error that I cancelled it.

I have tried on a personal proyect as well as with [Google's sample proyect](https://github.com/android/fit-samples), where other users are also [experiencing the same issue](https://github.com/android/fit-samples/issues/58).

As I describe on that issue, I have tested both apps on an emulator, a Huawei Pro 20 Lite, and on another device, with four different accounts, but get the same result.

Also have the correct configuration in the Google Cloud Console, using the proper applicationId and SHA1 signing key, I've tried on two different cloud projects, one of them brand new.

The function that launches the sign-in flow is this one, the full code from the sample app can be found [here](https://github.com/android/fit-samples/blob/main/BasicHistoryApiKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistoryapikotlin/MainActivity.kt)

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
    this,
    requestCode.ordinal,
    getGoogleAccount(), fitnessOptions)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Facing exact same issue here, had tested in two different devices, with two different google accounts (both added as tester), with both debug and release builds/certificates, all of them stuck at consent screen, WITHOUT ANY ERROR MESSAGE. Some said that we need to enable google authentication in the firebase project, tried that too and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, it strange but anyway it works for me:

- Delete your Cloud project
- Instead of the following instructions from http://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started  create a new project with firebase.
- Add an android app in firebase project settings
- Add both the SHA1 and SHA256 to it.
- Download google-services.json to android/app in your project folder.
- Make sure to have my "support email" set on general Project settings.

If this not help, please also check [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)

Guys have a similar problem with GoogleSignIn

Comment: I guess this is a good temporal fix, it's not what is detailed in the official documentation, but until Google sorts it out, it works.

Comment: It is not a solution for us, as our project is in production mode... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions at http://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started for registering an Android client.

Ensure that the Fit API is enabled for your Cloud project.

Check your credentials for your Cloud project:

- Ensure that your package name for your credentials matches the sample.
- Ensure the package name matches the applicationId in the app/build.gradle file.
- Ensure the Signing-certificate fingerprint is entered correctly.

**Additionally from OAuthConsentScreen add test users and set User Type to external**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've made sure I meet all the requirements you list, same result...