# Google Fit API login stuck at loading

Tags: android-studio, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin, google-fit

I'm trying to add login to my android studio app in Kotlin with OAuth2 Google, and it's keep loading and not login, what I have to do?

Comment: Same issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735897/oauth-consent-screen-blank-in-android-app-with-google-fit

Comment: thanks, but its seem that they don't solved the problem too..

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, it is strange but anyway it works for me:

- Delete your Cloud project
- Instead of the following instructions from http://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started  create a new project with firebase.
- Add an android app in firebase project settings
- Add both the SHA1 and SHA256 to it.
- Download google-services.json to android/app in your project folder.
- Make sure to have my "support email" set on general Project settings.

Now it should work.

If this not help, please also check [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)

Guys have a similar problem with GoogleSignIn

Comment: After I Add an Android App, create another Cloud Project? or not?