# Google sign in working on emulator but not on Android device flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

I'm developing a flutter app which includes google sign in with firebase. Google sign in is working perfectly on emulator but when I export signed bundle and test on physical device. It doesn't work. Is there anything I need to add in gradle file? Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the SHA1 and SHA256 for `release` and `debug` are different.

So since we have added only the `debug` keys, we also need to add the `release` keys.

For that we need to open **Google Play Console** > **(Click on your App)** > **Setup** in Left Pane > **App Integrity**

There you will get **App signing key certificate** and **Upload key certificate**

Copy the `SHA1` and `SHA256` from both keys and paste in Firebase Project under `Project Settings`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Goto Play store and Search for "App Integrity"

[image: Google play store app integrity]

Then

**Copy the SHA Keys** and Add into the Firebase signing keys.

and then you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add SHA1 and SHA256 keys in your firebase project, also add proper email id in the project setting while setting up the SHA keys.
2. Download the google-services file again
3. Rebuild the project
4. If you're planning to release the app on play store then you need to setup OAuth.

Comment: I've already added keys in there. But, I haven't setup OAuth. Can you please guide me how to do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: This will help for OAuth and playstore related setup for your app. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google/54696963#54696963 


This link will be helpful for OAuth and Credentials
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the release sha-1 to Firebase. Run signing report in Android Studio to get the sha-1 and add it to your Firebase project under Project Overview settings.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution for it. Actually the Google sign in was not working after I upload it to google play and then install it as a tester.
Problem was that the Google play generates different SHA1 and SHA256 keys. But, I had only added the keys from Android Studio and this was causing a problem.
I got the problem solved when I found SHA1 and SHA256 keys from Google play app and added them to firebase.
Thank you very much to the respected people who tried to help.

Comment: did you add keys you got from google play with the keys you generated from android studio OR remove the old ones and only put keys from the play store ... please help me.

Comment: We don't need to remove anything, just add the new keys