# Does Flutter Code Obfuscation Strip out Code in the Process?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I built an app with flutter and it has google sign in option.

I built the app using this command below and published to the Google Playstore

`flutter build appbundle --no-sound-null-safety --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols` Now users on playstore are complaining that they can no longer sign in with Google.

The error they are getting is `platformexception(sign_in_failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.apiexception 10 null null)`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Code obfuscation shouldn't interfere with the code logic itself. The issue is likely something else. Go through all the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google

Comment: I am not sure if Flutter is different, but code obfuscation in general is capable of mangling names such that other code can no longer find it. That's why there are ProGuard rules, right? That said, if the answers linked to in the preceding comment don't help you, then editing the question with full error + stacktrace might help us.