# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to use google signin in my flutter app but it keeps throwing error

> PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

I am using google singin through a button

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GoogleSignIn _google_sign_in = Provider.of<GoogleSignIn>(context, listen: false);
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = Provider.of<FirebaseAuth>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.40,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 250,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        try{
                          GoogleSignInAccount? googleCreds = await _google_sign_in.signIn();
                          if(googleCreds == null){
                            print('creds null');
                          }else{
                            final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleCreds.authentication;

                            final OAuthCredential credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                              accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
                              idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
                            );

                            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credentials);
                          }
                        }catch(e){
                          print(e.toString());
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Google'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 250,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/EmailLogin');
                      },
                      child: Text('Email'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my build gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my app level build gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.minor"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
}
```

I gave SHA1 and SHA256 to my firebase project and also have downloaded google-services.json.

Comment: just check if the SHA1 and SHA256 key is for release and not debug

Comment: Checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54557479/15117201