# flutter google sign in ApiException 10

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I created a OAuth consent screen and Credentials in console.cloud.google.com

This is my flutter code

```
      GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
          clientId: 'xxxx from console.cloud.google.com',
          scopes: [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
          ]
      );
```

and

```
  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      print('ok');
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

but I got this error:

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

thanks for your help!!

Comment: Check your the SHA if you put the Debug or Release SHA.

Comment: @mariofrancois i should create a new keystore or defualt in c:/user/NAME/.android and Debug or Release ?

Comment: Yes, if the build is release change to the SHA release.

Comment: @mariofrancois i create a new key and register it in build.gradle and  i got new sha-1 and submit in google cloud but i have the same error

Comment: Are you in Release Mode? Or build to release?

Comment: Can you please have a look at this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google) that got registered in SO for more information .

Answer (score 0):

Run `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android` to get your SHA-1 and SHA-256. If you are signing in with firebase, add these SHA codes to your firebase project settings.

Comment: no, i don't use firebase, i got sha-1 and submit in google cloud but i have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the right client ID with the right device ?
If you're running flutter on IOS for example, you need an iOS google client ID to make google sign in work.

Comment: i choose Application type = andoird in google cloud and i run app in avd in android studio