# Flutter Google SignIn Error after build apk

Tags: flutter, google-signin

Flutter app works appropriately in emulator but after build app is not working:

[image]

Comment: I think you have the same problem, already solved in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)

Answer (score 1):

Add SHA certificate fingerprints in your firebase project
by following steps:

**Step 1**

Make Sure You have java installed in your system

**Step 2**

Run the following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore"
```

enter password:

android