# Which SHA-1 key should I use to sign into a google account for email?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I need to be able to have the user sign into their Google account to send an email.

I am using the google_sign_in.dart package in my flutter app.

When I get to the line where a popup asks for the user to choose which Google account they want to use I get the popup just fine. However, I get this error:

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null))
```

The research I have done says this is because my Google project account is not setup correctly.

When I look at the project console I see that I have two sets of SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys.

Here are the two type of keys I have in my Google Console:

**App signing key certificate**

SHA-1

SHA-256

**Upload key certificate**

SHA-1

SHA-256

Which set of keys should I be using in my Firebase project configuration while I am testing it on my Android device?

Once I get the right key in my Firebase what should I see in my google-services.json file?

Here is what I currently have in my google-services.json file:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "##########",
    "firebase_url": "https://deal-diligence-5de73-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "deal-diligence-#####",
    "storage_bucket": "deal-diligence-#####.appspot.com" 
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:#########:android:dfbaae290896d469a51ef4",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.kane.dealdiligence"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyCoxOwgic8#####B2koLr44c###nDNmtOM"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

I don't see any reference to the SHA-1 key. Should I see a reference?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have registered your app's signing certificate fingerprints with the Firebase console for both SHA-1 and SHA-256. To obtain the fingerprints, you can use the following commands in your terminal or command prompt:

```
`keytool -list -v -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore` -alias alias_name
```

Also make sure that google sign in is activated on firebase. Then download a new version of your services.google.json file.

Comment: Thanks, I have done all of that. I have added both sets of SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys but I get the same error. Maybe there is something else I need to setup in the Google Play account? How do I know?

Comment: The only thing that i can recommend is to go through these steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google

Comment: Dont forget to clean and run pub get once installed the new version of the services.google.json file