PlatfromException(sign_in_failed,h1.b:10:,null,null) even my release and debug SHA-1 and SHA-256 key is correct
I created an application that worked fine, and its apk-release also functions properly for Google sign-in. However, when I publish my application for closed testing, I encounter this error:

Error for sign-in
I sought a solution here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037554/22246996 , but in my case, the Google Play option displays this:

I believe the issue might be resolved once it's deployed, and then I can see its release SHA and update it in my Firebase. Please advise on the solution.

I am assuming you are using Google Play App Signing to sign the release build, and I can confirm that you do not need to wait.
Head over to your Google Play Developer account and Click on Setup > App Signing. If you have already created a release track, you should be able to set up the app and see your SHA1 release key.
I just created a new app on my console and was able to set it up and get a SHA1 without uploading any app bungle.


