Keep getting the error Google Sign-In Error: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
I'm trying to implement google sign-in for my app without firebase.
I seem to have done all the steps suggested in the documentations, and for other answers, but i still keep getting this error:

Google Sign-In Error: PlatformException(sign_in_failed,
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)




Steps taken:

Added necessary information for OAuth consent screen

--

Added package name and SHA1 fingerprint in the google cloud console for my app:



Got the SHA1 fingerprint (running gradlew signingReport command)


Added it with package name



--

Implemented the code:


AndroidManifest.xml (internet permissions are there)

This client Id is there in strings.xml

in app/build.gradle
     signingConfigs {
         debug {
             keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
             keyPassword '*****'
             storeFile file('mykey.jks')
             storePassword '*****'
         }
     }

     buildTypes {
         debug {
             signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
         }
     }

dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
    }


in android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        }
    }
}


Flutter login.dart
class LoginAPI {
  static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> login() => _googleSignIn.signIn();
  static Future signOut = _googleSignIn.signOut();
}

onPressed: () async {
    var user = await LoginAPI.login();
    print('user.....');
    print(user);
},



What am I doing wrong? Are there any more steps I'm missing.
NOTE: I'm implementing Google sign in without Firebase, as we also have a api to handle login.
So google-services.json has not been added.
Any solutions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google
did not help with the current issue for the same reason.
Any other steps not involving firebase, and relevant to current implementation were already taken.

This question is similar to: Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, at first i went to that and similar posts for help. I have added a note for that. @A-E

At what step exactly are you getting the error? Based on the other posts linked this is frustratingly a generic catch-all error so the error message alone may not be enough info to solve your problem

Yes right!!!  So I'm able to successfully run the flutter app, and there aren't any issues there, as soon as we click on 'sign in with google' button and select an email - it fails and the sign it doesn't get successful
So at this step -> _googleSignIn.signIn(),
await _googleSignIn.signIn();
before being able to successfully get user information/ or even complete sign-in process, it fails.  @Marsroverr

Are there any logs on the google cloud console that could help you narrow down the issue?

That's the main problem, there aren't any other helpful logs :( . I have added an error screenshot with more error consoles I'm able to produce in some cases. Doesn't really help much with debugging. @Marsroverr

Found the issue with this-
It was because of the incorrect key SHA-1 key.
For people implementing google sign-in without firebase:

First, run flutter doctor command:
flutter doctor -v


It will return the java bin library path:
Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java


Create you jks file:
keytool -genkey -v -keystore '<path\wher\you\want\to\create\it\file_name.jks> -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias 'your_alias'


Add details as requested, once the file is created - go to that path.


Move the file to your projects 'android/app/' folder


Run this command in android studio keytool -list -v -keystore <path\to\your\jks\file>


Enter you password:


Copy the SHA-1 key returned (We will be using this key)


Add this sha fingerprint to you google cloud console.

Google sign-in should work as expected.
