flutter - Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
I'm getting this error:

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`

There are a few things about this that make it I think potentially may be the issue. I have an existing app that I'm rewriting from scratch. The existing app has google sign in, and I'm using the same firebase account. Also, when I started writing the new app, I used the wrong package, so I changed the package name to the correct one. Originally, I was going to use a new firebase project, and was able to use google sign in with the different package and firebase account.
So, could this be related to the fact that another live app is using the firebase app?
I've confirmed I have done the following:

set the SHA1 and SHA256 in firebase
confirmed google sign in is enabled on firebase
run flutter clean, flutter doctor, invalidated caches and restart
have the same package name on app and on firebase
downloaded the new google-services.json


check out this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54557479/13565633

Perhaps this answer will help.

yep - I'm familiar with both of those. Unfortunately, after trying all of the above, still getting the issue

Just in case this helps someone, here's what finally helped me:
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(
        scopes: ['email', 'profile'],
        hostedDomain: '',
      ).signIn();


I was facing the same issue, it was already working but suddenly it stopped, all I did was remove SHA1 and SHA256 in Firebase, update google_sign_in to the latest version, and then generate new SHA1 & SHA256, add these new keys in Firebase and worked.
Generate SHA1 & SHA256
You can also check this answer

Try this configure firebase this code flutterfire configure and flutter clean and flutter pub get

try this but not solved
